# How to insert Tab Stop in nested list items for Python

Tags: python, tabs, indentation

I am running Python 2.7.8 on my PC.

But this book I am reading uses Python 3.0, and the following code prints items and nested items, if any.

```
def print_it(the_list, level=0):
    for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item, list):
            print_it(each_item, level+1)
        else:
            for tab_stop in range(level):
                print("\t", end='')
            print(each_item)
```

This particular code

```
for tab_stop in range(level):
    print("\t", end='')
```

inserts a tab on nested list items.

However, the code does not work for Python 2.7.8.

What is the equivalent of this in Python 2.7.8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your python code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

This will ensure that `print` can be used only as a function as it is in Python 3.